# How to solve "Invalid time zone specified: ..." date-fns-tz error in react-native?

Tags: react-native, timezone, expo, date-fns

I have a mobile application made with expo SDK 45, which its main feature is related to times,

So I opted to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) to manage and format the time in the application... Unfortunately for some TimeZone, the `format()` method does not return the date selected in the calendar.

For example, being in the United States/NewYork timeZone, if I select `2022-06-23` in the calendar and I pass it in the `format()` method it gives me `2022-06-22`
But if I enter in Europe/Paris timeZone everything works fine...

I did some research and came across [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz), which is a support for data-fns to handle timeZones. the problem, when I try to use the `formatInTimeZone()` method for example, I get this error every time: `'Invalid time zone specified: ...'` But I'm sure I've implemented the code correctly from the documentation...

I.e:

```js
const { formatInTimeZone } = require('date-fns-tz')

const date = new Date('2014-10-25T10:46:20Z')

formatInTimeZone(date, 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX') // 2014-10-25 06:46:20-04:00
```

The above code systematically returns an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by installing [date-time-format-timezone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-time-format-timezone) as a dependency and importing it from the root of my application

Currently my app entry file (App.tsx) looks like this:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US';
import 'date-time-format-timezone';

import App from './src/App';

export default App;
```