# "Invalid time zone specified" with date-fns-tz in React Native

Tags: react-native, timezone, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I have an Expo project and use date-fns and date-fns-tz to manipulate time and timezones.

Regarless of the timezone I use (Europe/Paris, UTC, America/New_York'...), I get the following error:

> Invalid time zone specified: Europe/Paris

I've tried to copy/paste the example from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz#formatintimezone), but same thing.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import { formatDuration, intervalToDuration, parseISO } from "date-fns";
import { formatInTimeZone} from "date-fns-tz";
formatInTimeZone(
      date,
      "Europe/Paris",
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX"
    );
```

I've tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72693276/893204) but my app gets errors.

Using `"date-fns": "^2.16.1"` and     `"date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7"`.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with react-native(CLI) and doesn`t achieved to resolve the problem. I saw something about a version of hermes, I think in react-native 0.59 or higher this is solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).